# The mdl-data-table--selectable table can't change the line-height in CSS?

Tags: material-design-lite

The mdl-data-table--selectable table can't change the line-height in CSS.
So how to make rows shorter?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height. Issue is mostly with the padding around the checkboxes. This worked for me to reduce the line height:

```
.mdl-data-table--selectable tr,.mdl-data-table--selectable td, .mdl-data-table--selectable th{
    height: 15px!important;
    padding: 0em;
    padding-left: 24px;

}
```

However you'll need to manually clean up the presentation a bit if you really want to do this because it screws with the mdl layout.